# How to save a compute engine VM-instance setup in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have created a compute engine VM-instance in Google Cloud Platform. Then I have installed go using the standard procedure downloading it from https://dl.google.com/go/go1.11.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz. Everything worked properly and I was able to run go application. However, after closing the instance when I reopened it, it says go is not installed. The message is following.

`-bash: go: command not found`

How can I save the instance setup?

Comment: did u ran using an environment ?

Comment: You mean the VM-instance or the application?

Comment: Were you using Google Cloud Shell?

Answer (score 0):

[Creating, Deleting, and Deprecating Custom Images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#bundle_image)

> You can create custom images of boot disks and use these images to create new instances. This is ideal for situations where you have created and modified a persistent boot disk to a certain state and need to save that state to create new instances.

I think you should also consider using Docker containers.

[Pushing and pulling images](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling)

[Container-optimized VM images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/)